# Let $g$ maps from a unit disk $D$ to itself with the modulo of $g(z) \leq 1/2$. Prove that $|g(z)-g(0) \leq |z|$ for all $z \in D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I'm still confused with this question.  Let $g$ maps from a unit disk $D$ to itself with the modulo of $g(z) \leq 1/2$.  Prove that $|g(z)-g(0) \leq |z|$ for all $z \in D$.

What I did is this

As $g(z)$ is analytic in $D$, $g(z)$ is continuous and differentiable in $D$.  Then
$\left|\frac{g(z) - g(0)}{z-0} \right| \leq \epsilon$.  Choose $\epsilon = 1/2$.  Then we have

$|g(z) - g(0)| \leq |z-0|\epsilon$

I don't know how to continue with this. I just had a feeling it might be of $\epsilon = 1/2$ but I am confused with the proof now.  Can you help me? I would much appreciate that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(z)=g(z)-g(0)$. Then $|h(z)| \leq 1$ so   $h$ maps the unit disk to its closure and vanishes at $0$. By Schwarz Lemma we get $|h(z)| \leq |z|$.

Comment: Wow. thanks Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: By the way, Professor Kavi, why can we use the Schwarz Lemma? It says there that the function $f: D \rightarrow D$ is holomorphic and $f(0) = 0$. Are we assuming that h(0) = 0?  Sorry I'm confused.

Comment: $h(z)=g(z)-g(0)$, so $h(0)=g(0)-g(0)=0$, and then you can use the Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: Ah Ok thanks so much, Vinicius. SO much help